# sugarcrm Sidecar and clients tutorial

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

I am not good at sugarcrm sidecars framework and clients also try to get from lot of tutorial but can't find explanatory tutorial of it. can anyone guide me for the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally dev link is: https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer - here you could find the most fresh info. Next links I found using search there (probably you'll be able to find more):

https://community.sugarcrm.com/docs/DOC-4823-tutorial-adding-a-custom-component-in-the-side-pane

https://community.sugarcrm.com/community/developer/blog/2017/11/06/how-to-create-custom-sidecar-routes